# Problem with declaration of array of jtextarea

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextarea

When I am declaring the array of jtextarea using the following code:
`tabs[i] = new javax.swing.JTextArea();`
I am getting the following error:
java.lang.NullPointerException

the tabs variable is declared as follows outside the procedure in which tabs[i] is declared:

```
private static javax.swing.JTextArea tabs[];
```

Can someone please explain me why I am getting this error??
-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you've written so far, you've not yet instanciated your array :

```
private static javax.swing.JTextArea tabs[] = new javax.swing.JTextArea tabs[5];
```

Besdies, i would recommand you to use collections instead of arrays, as they are so XXth century (and you have far easier way to handle dynamically sized collections).

Comment: Can you please give an example for using collections in the above context??

Comment: List< JTextArea > tabs = new LinkedList< JTextArea >(); ... tabs.add( new JTextArea() );